# "git pull" runs out of memory

Tags: git, github

I tired to git pull, it suddenly comes out ..

Please let me know what I have to do

```
git pull
remote: Counting objects: 196, done.
remote: warning: suboptimal pack - out of memory
remote: fatal: Out of memory, malloc failed (tried to allocate 220610561 bytes)
error: git upload-pack: git-pack-objects died with error.
fatal: git upload-pack: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
remote: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Comment: `remote: fatal: Out of memory` My guess would be that someone ran out of memory...

Comment: so, do I have to expand memory on gitlab?

Comment: It looks like the process on your local machine is running out of memory. Is it a particularly large repo? I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: It's unlikely to be on the *local* machine, those remote messages are from the other end as it packages up the changes for efficient delivery. Contact the repo maintainer.

Comment: Gotta love that cascade of critical errors as the server process just melts down.

Comment: @paxdiablo: You're right, it does say "remote: fatal: Out of memory...".  The message "aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side" is also telling. DHC, you mentioned gitlab in a comment, but not in your question. If you're using gitlab, and if it's relevant, add that information to the question -- but it looks like you're just using the `git` shell command.

Comment: @JDB, remonds me of the effects of missing one `.` in my old COBOL code (showing my age here) and having 742 errors generated as a result :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have access to the remote server, try to open an ssh session on it and type:

```
git config pack.windowMemory 10m
git config pack.packSizeLimit 20m
```

But if you don't , you will have to do some shallow fetch, in order to *not* fetch the all history at once.

```
git clone /url/of/remote/repo --depth=1
git fetch --depth=10
git fetch --depth=20
...
git fetch --depth=100
git fetch --unshallow    //Downloads all history allowing to push from repo
```

Comment: I tried the fetch, depth things caused same errors, and --unshallow gives the comment fatal: --unshallow on a complete repository does not make sence..

Comment: @DHC Did you try the fetch in a branc new shallow clone? Or in your existing cloned local repo?